# Why is there just garbage data in texture layers beyond 2048?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, opengl-4

I am trying to use a texture_2d_array with up to 8192 layers. But all layers after the 2048th just contain garbage data (tested by mapping the individual layers on a quad to visualize the texture).
Querying the maximum number of layers with

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS, &maxTexLayers);
```

returns 8192 for my graphics card (AMD 5770), the same for an AMD 7850er. My only other available graphics card is an NVidia 480, which supports just 2048 layers.

I use the following code to create the texture:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, tex);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 7);

glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 8, GL_RGB8, 128, 128, 8192);
//glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGB, 128, 128, 8192, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

std::vector<char> image = readImage(testImagePath);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 8192; ++i)
{
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, 128, 128, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data());
}

GLuint tLoc = glGetUniformLocation (program, "texArray");
glProgramUniform1i (program, tLoc, 0);
```

(here https://mega.co.nz/#!FJ0gzIoJ!Kk0q_1xv9c7sCTi68mbKon1gDBUM1dgjrxoBJKTlj6U you can find a cut-down version of the program)

I am out of ideas:

1. Changing glTexStorage3D to glTexImage3D - no change
2. Playing with the base/max level - no change
3. Min_Filter to GL_LINEAR - no change
4. generating mipmaps (glGenerateMipmaps) - no change
5. reducing the size of the layers to e.g. 4x4 - no change
6. reducing the number of layers to e.g. 4096 - no change
7. switching to an AMD 7850 - no change
8. enabling debug context - no errors
9. etc. and a lot of other stuff

So, it could be a driver bug with the driver reporting the wrong number for GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS, but maybe I missed something and one of you has an idea.

EDIT: I am aware that such a texture would use quite a lot of memory and even if my graphics card had that much available OpenGL does not guarantee that I can allocate it, but I am getting no errors with the debug context enabled, especially no OUT_OF_MEMORY and I also tried it with a size of 4x4 per layer, which would be just 512kb

Comment: I am assuming this question is also yours: http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/160796? If not there is someone else banging his head into the same brick wall...

Comment: your assumption is correct ;)

Comment: I hope you reported this to the AMD driver developers.

Answer (score 4):

2 things:

1) Wouldn't 8192 textures that are 128x128 be over 500MBs of data? (Or 400MB if it's RGB instead of RGBA.) It could be that OpenGL can't allocate that much memory, even if your card has that much, due to fragmentation or other issues.

2) Just because OpenGL says the max is 8192 (or larger) doesn't mean that you're guaranteed to be able to use that much in every case. For example, my driver claims that the card can handle a max texture size of 8192 on a side. But if I try to create an 4096x4096 image that's 32-bit floating point RGBA, it fails, even though it's only 268MB and I have a Gig of VRAM.

Does `glGetError()` return any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I slightly extended my initial post.
yes, an RGB8 texture of this size would be 384mb, but I also tried using texture compression (DXT1) which reduces the size to about 64mb or using smaller layers, e.g. 4x4 (512kb).
I have not tried the extreme case of 1x1x8192xR8 yet, but such a texture would be quite useless.

Comment: additionally to the debug context I also used glGetError(), but no errors occurred.